# Cordova issue with $.getJSON API

Tags: javascript, php, json, cordova, content-security-policy

I'm working on a developing an app for a university project using Cordova so it's my first time using it. As part of it, I've managed to implement an API from Reed Jobs and this is working fine in Chrome, however it won't work on the iOS emulator - there are no errors but the page just doesn't load any data.

I'm using `$.getJSON("reed.php", function(data)` in my JavaScript to call my data, and then my PHP is as follows...

```
<?php

$username = "username";
$password = "";
$remoteUrl = 'https://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?locationName=leeds&distancefromlocation=15&partTime=true&temp=true';

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")                 
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($remoteUrl, false, $context);

print($file);
?>
```

After reading some suggestions, I've tried adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;**script-src 'self' https://www.reed.co.uk/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';** ">` to my html page, but this presents me a list of errors in my console:

```
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive '**script-src'.
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive '**'.
Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,500,700,900' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index.js:31
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at window.onload
```

And then I also tried adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src http://reed.co.uk https://reed.co.uk">` which gave me the error of:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://example.com/reed.php' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src http://reed.co.uk https://reed.co.uk".
```

Can anybody help me? My understanding of the meta tags is not very established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSP is set to http://reed.co.uk https://reed.co.uk but your call points to https://example.com

Try this?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src http://reed.co.uk https://reed.co.uk https://example.com">
```